# C Runtime Memory Leak Check Fails in SDK 10.0.14393.0

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015

We are engineering a DLL that invokes, for Debug configuration builds, a Visual Studio C Runtime library memory leak check via:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

Specifically, the _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF flag is documented to invoke this behavior:

> ON: Perform automatic leak checking at program exit through a call to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks and generate an error report if the application failed to free all the memory it allocated. OFF: Do not automatically perform leak checking at program exit.

What this means for a DLL is that when the DLL is unloaded, the leak check is done.  So just running a Debug build for us automatically tells us if a memory leak has recently been coded-in.  Very nice to have.

Up through SDK version 10.0.10586.0 it worked just as expected.  If we neglected to release a block of RAM, it popped up and told us so.

With SDK version 10.0.14393.0, if there IS a leak, it just either locks up the application or causes it to crash/exit.  If Visual studio is attached to the host process for debugging, we do see a message in the Debug output sent to the Ouput window, but under no conditions can we get the pop-up any longer.

If I revert the Target Platform Version back to 10.0.10586.0 and rebuild it works just as expected again.

Beyond the obvious workaround - revert to 10.0.10586.0 - does anyone here have any ideas how this corruption/failure/crash can be averted?

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.

Comment: Hmm, you are assuming that your app *only* has leak problems.  But you are describing a scenario that strongly suggest you actually have a heap corruption problem.  You can't really assume that a different CRT version will corrupt memory the same way.  If you are still convinced that 14393 has a bug and it is not a problem induced by your code then you'll have to give Microsoft Support a call to get ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your note, Hans.  We actually have a LEAK_HERE macro we use to force a check of the leak check logic.  We're quite sure the DLL is running clean otherwise, without heap corruption, and in fact it runs all the way through without the application fault if we don't force the leak.  I hesitate to involve Microsoft until I'm sure I'm not just missing something about the _CrtSetDbg... functionality, though we've scoured all the documentation for anything that would explain this change in behavior and have come up empty.